# Showing and Hiding a submit button on focus/blur

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, coffeescript

I want to have a text area form that expands from 1 row to 4 when focussed, and also reveals the otherwise hidden submit button - the same as the twitter website.

I have a working script, but the problem is that when you click the submit button, it is hidden (focus is gone), so you can't actually submit the text.

Here's the code (coffee script - for a rails form)

```
$('.status-content').focus (event) ->
$(this).attr('rows', '4',)
$('.status-create').show()

$('.status-content').blur (event) ->
$(this).attr('rows', '1')
$('.status-create').hide()
```

The .status-content is the text area class, and the .status-create is the submit button class.

Any ideas on how to hide the button when focus is off, but still submit the text?

Based on Alex's advised, I tried to add a setTimeout:

```
$('.status-content').focus (event) ->
  $(this).attr('rows', '4',)
  $('.status-create').show()

$('.status-content').blur (event) ->
  setTimeout ->
    $(this).attr('rows', '1')
    $('.status-create').hide()
  , 100
```

Although I can submit now, the text area stays at 4 rows when focus is lost.

Comment: Figured it out - in the setTimeout function, need to change 'this' to '.status-content'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to check if the textarea is not empty (no coffee script):

```
$('.status-content').blur(function(event) {
   if ($(this).text().length) {

   }
   else {
      $(this).attr('rows', '1');
      $('.status-create').hide();
   }
});
```

Or you do a little trick:

```
var timer;

$('.status-content').blur(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).attr('rows', '1');
    $('.status-create').hide();
    }, 100);
});

$('.status-create').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Comment: I rewrote this into coffessscript. The timeout seems to get halfway there - can now submit, but when focus is off, the text area doesn't go back to 1 row.

Comment: $('.status-content').focus (event) ->
  $(this).attr('rows', '4',)
  $('.status-create').show()

 $('.status-content').blur (event) ->
  setTimeout ->
   $(this).attr('rows', '1')
   $('.status-create').hide()
  , 100

Answer (score 0):

Just do correct your code. It would make more sense to have

```
$('.status-content').on 'focus', ->
  $(this).attr('rows', '4',)
  $('.status-create').show()

$('.status-content').on 'blur', -> 
  $(this).attr('rows', '1')
  $('.status-create').hide()
```

Comment: This didn't help much I'm afraid - the button still disappears before the content is submitted